# Kotlin equivalent to Groovy spead-dot (*.)

Tags: groovy, collections, kotlin

Given the following code to get a list of all account numbers in one nice list I have to do the following:

```
data class Customer(val accounts : List<Account>)
data class Account(val number : String)

fun getCustomers() = arrayListOf(
    Customer(
        arrayListOf(Account("1"),Account("2"))
    ),
    Customer(
        arrayListOf(Account("3"),Account("4"))
    )
)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // long
    println(getCustomers().map{ it.accounts }.flatten().map{ it.number })
    // a little shorter (just discovered while typing the question)
    println(getCustomers().flatMap{ it.accounts }.map{ it.number })
```

[Playground Link](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/65mgo770kfs3h0paf2l69soohv/2cha0nl35um6fc5v2ptkg8gtdt)

In Groovy given the same class structure I could do:

```
    println(getCustomers()*.accounts*.number.flatten())
    // or even
    println(getCustomers().accounts.number.flatten())
```

[Playground Link](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5126581479538688)

Which is a little bit nicer. Is it possible to "create" an operator (say *.) to do similar to the Groovy version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create new operators in Kotlin.